# MVC 5 refresh page from controller called by AJAX call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a page where I display a register form on modal window.
I call Register action on controller via AJAX.
When the user input is wrong I reload the form and display the error summary. This works fine.
The problem is, when the register is successfull, I want to refresh the page, so the modal window closes and the user's list get refreshed.
But I cannot get it working.
My view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterSubordinate", "ManageUsers", null,
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    AllowCache = false,
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    UpdateTargetId = "_Register"
                }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "UserRegisterForm" }))
            {

            }
```

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> RegisterSubordinate(RegisterViewModel model, FormCollection collection)
{            
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ... I register the user here and want to refresh the page

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    //this works it reloads the form in the modal window
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return PartialView("_Register", model); 
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Please Use location.reload(): It will reload the same page with updated Information.

```
$('#something').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```